# Tags <script> cut out of the field <textarea> after the form is submitted

Tags: php, html, forms, apache, kohana

I have an issue with sending POST data from my form. There is a `<textarea>` in the form where i'm trying to paste some data which contain a tag `<script>` (e.g. a code of counter for website traffic, it doesn't matter).

```
<form action="/savepage" method="POST">
   <button type="submit">Save</button>
    <fieldset>
            <textarea name="content">
              Some <b>text</b>
              <script src="script_source" type="text/javascript"></script>
            </textarea>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

After the form was submitted I receive the `$_POST` array which contains all fields of my form, but tags `<script>` are missing in the `$_POST['content']` variable. This problem does not occur when I insert any other tags in the same field.

```
var_dump($_POST["content"]);
```

gives

> string(18) "Some `<b>text</b>`
>
> "

Can anybody explain me what happens with the tags `<script>` in the `<textarea>` field when submitting the form and why they are absent in the `$_POST['content']` variable? The back-end of my site is on the Kohana Framework v.2.4. Perhaps it's Kohana who cut  tags... Or, maybe, is there an option in the Apacahe or PHP settings which can do this things?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure they don't event show up in the page source ?

Comment: use addslashes($_POST["content"]);

Comment: addslashes($_POST["content"]) not works because there are no <script> tags in the $_POST["content"] variable

Comment: @khomyakoshka Do you put the ``<script>`` tag in the source or do you submit it by adding it manually to the form? If you put it in before take a look at my answer ;-))

Comment: @thedom, I submit it by adding it manually to the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the `<script>`-tag in before, you need to encode it, so that the browser does not parse the content

So - use `htmlspecialchars()`:

```
<form action="/savepage" method="POST">
   <button type="submit">Save</button>
    <fieldset>
            <textarea name="content">
<?php echo(htmlspecialchars('
              Some <b>text</b>
              <script src="script_source" type="text/javascript"></script>'); ?>
            </textarea>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: If I want to paste js script from the clipboard htmlspecialchars() will not help me

Comment: @khomyakoshka that's the problem with your question. It was not clear to me, so I asked again. Then you will need to ``htmlspecialchars()`` it afterwards. ``<?php echo(htmlspecialchars($_POST['content'])); ?>`` - if that doesn't work I guess that a function manipulates the GPC array

Comment: Try to explain. I copy any data to the clipboard, and then insert it into the field. After that I send the form. And on the server side I get the POST array with 'content' element that contains all other tags  pasted into the <textarea>, except the <script> tags

Comment: I don't know your code base. But it nearly ___has___ to be anything that manipulates your ``$_POST`` elements. It may be a global function which gets executed automatically. Check that back. http://pastie.org/4567888 Take a look at that... that works ;-))

Comment: Thank you for your help. The back-end of my site is on the Kohana Framework v.2.4. Perhaps it's Kohana who cut <script> tags, but I haven't found such place in the code of the framework, 
even though I tried, honestly.

Comment: I don't know Kohana Framework... but googling supposes me that Kohana is sanitizing inputs (http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/api/Kohana_Core)

Comment: Oh, thank you again. This documentation is for Kohana 3 but I've found the place in the kernel of my version of the framework where javascripts are removed =)

Answer (score 1):

Because that is being parsed as HTML `script` tag instead of being treated as text. Use html-entities for parsing it as text.

So, it'll be:

```
&lt;script src=&quot;script_source&quot; type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Now I solve it this way. I wrote a JS function that parses the inputed data and replaces the tags <script> on {{--script--}}. On the server side I replace {{-- to < and --}} to > in the $_POST["content"] variable.